# Change numbers in this form: 0.873000 / 0,234000 into this form: 87 / 23

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, scripting, bioinformatics

From a file like this one (phylogenetic tree in which branch supports are between  0 and 1):

```
(AJirio:0.00207,(AJama:0.00176,(AJtok:0.00034,AJkago:0.00057)0.832000:0.00080)0.934000:0.00111)0.923000
```

I need to obtain this (phylogenetic tree in which branch supports are integers between 0 and 100):

```
(AJirio:0.00207,(AJama:0.00176,(AJtok:0.00034,AJkago:0.00057)83:0.00080)93:0.00111)92
```

The differences between the two are in bold. Does anyone know how to do it? Maybe with awk?

Comment: Why did .832 turn into 83 and not 8?

Comment: You probably don't want to be manipulating data like this with regular expressions in simple awk or sed scripts.  You're almost certainly better off using [bioperl](http://bioperl.org) or [biopython](http://biopython.org) or similar.   Also, both https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ and [biostars](https://www.biostars.org/) seem like good sites for bioinformatics Q&A.

Comment: It's not a problem because I can copy the data before manipulating them. I don't have any knowledge in perl or python..

Comment: "Why did 0.832 turn into 83 and not 8?" Because I want to mutiply it by 100, I forgot to clarify it.

Comment: I assumed you'd work on a copy (that's **always** a good idea). My comment was pointing out that it's much easier to work with such data using tools designed for the purpose, tools that know how to parse, manipulate, and generate the commonly used data formats used in the various bioinformatics/life-sciences fields.

Comment: as per the subject of your question, do you really want to consider either the period or comma as the decimal radix? (both `0.83` and `0,83` changed to `83`)?

Comment: How should rounding be done? Should `0.838` be `83` or `84`? What about `0.835`?

Comment: The decimal radix is always a period in the file, the comma is used to seperate the species in the tree (AJirio, AJama) so it should just stay as it is. Ideally 0.838 should become 0.84 but if it's easier to write a script that will change it into 0.83 that will do :)

Comment: I know nothing about bioinformatics, so this may be a dumb question, but: Are there always exactly three things on each line?  Three pairs of parentheses and three numbers that need to be multiplied by 100?  (Can there be more?)

Comment: No, I just put a very simple tree but you can have as many pairs of parentheses as you want but the number of branch support (the numbers I needed to multiply by 100) is always the same as the number of pairs of parentheses. The number after the ")" is always the branch support, and the number after ":" the branch length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easy with `sed`,
if all the data look like the sample data:

```
sed -e 's/)0\.0\(.\)[0-9]*/)\1/g' -e 's/)0\.\(..\)[0-9]*/)\1/g' -e 's/)1\.00[0-9]*/)100/g' file
```

This has three `-e` subcommands, which are variations on the same theme. 
Each one looks for a `)` followed by a decimal number
between 0.00 and 1.00, with at least two decimal digits,
and replaces it with a `)` followed by the corresponding integer
between 0 and 100. 
Each one ends with `g` to make it global,
so it affects any number of branch supports on each line. 
Unfortunately, this truncates numbers rather than rounding,
so `0.838` becomes `83` rather than `84`.

Details:

- `s/)0\.0\(.\)[0-9]*/)\1/g`
  Looks for a number beginning with `0.0` (e.g., `0.00` or `0.07`)
  and replaces it with just the second decimal digit,
  so `0.00` and `0.07` become `0` and `7` rather than `00` and `07`. 
  `[0-9]*` matches any number of digits after the second one
  and discards them (by replacing them with nothing).
- `s/)0\.\(..\)[0-9]*/)\1/g`
  This is the general case: `0.` followed by something other than a `0`. 
  This changes `0.832000` to `83`, etc.
- `s/)1\.00[0-9]*/)100/g`
  This looks for `1.00` and changes it to `100`. 
  If you’re sure that this will never appear in your data,
  you can leave off this subcommand.

If, as you suggest in your question title,
you also want to be able to change `0,234000`
(with a comma as a decimal mark) to `23`,
change `\.` to `[,.]` in each of the subcommands.

Comment: @DavidB, welcome to SE. If you deem that answer to work for you, will you please mark G-Man's answer as the best answer by checking it with the green check mark left of the body of the answer ?  This will help others identify the issue as solved and go directly to the accepted (and supposedly "best") answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use awk to extract the required content from the file using below command (`temp.txt` is the input file):

```
awk -F ")" '{print $1 ")" substr($2,3,2) substr($2,9) ")" substr($3,3,2) substr($3,9) ")" substr($4,3,2) }' temp.txt
```

Comment: It's not working, probably because there are no "**" in my file. I used them to show the numbers I wanted to change in bold, but then someone edited my post and it's not in bold anymore.. I tried to use the same line without "**" and it's not working neither.

Comment: ok but apparently it's making my comment in bold.. I meant the "2 stars"

Comment: (1) The OP has clarified that there can be any number of “branch supports” (i.e., sets of parentheses) in a line.   Your command assumes that there are exactly three, and fails if there are more or fewer.   I realize that the OP didn’t issue this clarification until after you posted your answer.   While it’s reasonable to assume that the real input looks like the sample input (absent any clarifying statement) up to a point, it’s a good idea to identify what assumptions you are making (i.e., that your code depends on) and state them in your answer.   Or post a comment on the question … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  asking for confirmation.  I realize that you don’t have the privilege to comment yet; it requires 50 reputation points.  (2) Your command assumes that all the numbers to be changed in the input are of the form `0.nnnnnn`.  Your command fails if there are more or fewer than six decimal digits.  See point #1.  (3) A nasty side effect of point #2 is that your code changes an input of `1.000000` to `00` rather than `100`.  Since the question says that the numbers are between 0 and 1, you might have thought about this (although I concede that the word “between” is ambiguous). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Similarly, your code converts `0.008395` and `0.034567` to `00` and `03`, respectively, rather than `0` and `3`. I realize that the leading zero might be acceptable (or maybe even desired) and that the question did not say anything about how to handle the case of numbers < ``0.100000``. (5) We prefer answers that provide a command (or code) ***and*** explain it. See [my answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/420654/80216#420854) for an example. … … Aside from the above, this is a pretty good first answer. Write a few more like this and you’ll probably have those 50 rep points soon!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat test.txt
(AJirio:0.00207,(AJama:0.00176,(AJtok:0.00034,AJkago:0.00057)0.832000:0.00080)0.934000:0.00111)0.923000

$  awk -F\) '{for(i=NF-2;i<=NF;i++){split($i,arr,":");$i=sprintf("%2d:%s",arr[1]*100,arr[2])}}1' OFS=\) test.txt | sed "s/:$//"
(AJirio:0.00207,(AJama:0.00176,(AJtok:0.00034,AJkago:0.00057)83:0.00080)93:0.00111)92
```

Comment: (1) The OP has clarified (after you posted your answer) that there can be any number of “branch supports” (i.e., sets of parentheses) in a line.  +1 for handling it anyway — except you didn’t get it exactly right (try it and see).  You can fix this simply by changing the `i=NF-2` initialization to `i=2`.  (2) Your code converts `0.008395` and `0.034567` to `⁠   0` and `⁠   3` (with a leading space), respectively, rather than `0` and `3`.  You can fix this simply by changing `%2d` to `%d`.  (3) Using `sed` to remove the extra `:` at the end of the line is simple and effective.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  But `awk`, `sed`, and `perl` are such powerful tools that it’s rarely necessary to use more than one of them in a single command (or to use `grep` with any of them). You can handle that entirely in `awk` (hint: by not printing the `:` in the first place); care to try?  (4) The `OFS=\)` after the awk program works, but is not commonly used. Many people would rather put `-vOFS=\)` before the program.  5) We prefer answers that provide a command (or code) ***and*** explain it. See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420654/80216#420854) for an example explanation.